# --build configuration option prior to compiling mono from a git source code checkout

Tags: mono, autogen

Recently I compiled mono from source in order to use it with asp.net vnext

I followed the instructions at [Compiling Mono on OS X](http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_on_OSX)

Built using a git source code checkout.

One of the steps includes the following bash command:

```
CC='cc -m32' ./autogen.sh --prefix=$PREFIX --disable-nls --build=i386-apple-darwin11.2.0
```

Please explain the `--build` option when compiling mono on os x, I am trying to understand what different values I can pass to it and what they do. I could not find any mention of this option in the [readme on github](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/README.md). So far I've only been able to deduce that omitting the option is required to compile mono in 64bit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--build` option is related to the GNU build system.

Check out this link: [gcc, Configure Terms and History](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Configure-Terms.html)

**--build:** it is the machine where you are building mono

By default, if you do not specify its value, it will be found out running the script called `config.guess`, which basically runs the `uname` command (`config.guess` is part of the automake system, which you should have in order to build mono)

Run the `config.guess` script if you want to know what values `autogen.sh` is going to use by default.

By the way, I do not have `OS X` but I think, in order to build mono in 64bit mode you should run `autogen.sh` without `CC='cc -m32'`

EDIT

Just for fun, reading the `config.guess` script, for `OS X` the default values would be the result of running this:

```
UNAME_RELEASE=`(uname -r) 2>/dev/null` || UNAME_RELEASE=unknown
UNAME_PROCESSOR=`uname -p` || UNAME_PROCESSOR=unknown
echo ${UNAME_PROCESSOR}-apple-darwin${UNAME_RELEASE}
```